# How to make an onclick html button in markdown to view a table?

Tags: html, markdown

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question as I am a new to this.

I am trying to create a markdown file to document a data analytics mini case study that I am doing. I wanted to make it a little bit presentable so I can use it later for my portfolio.

My first markdown looked like this:

### Data Inspection

- Check the total number of records

  ```sql
  SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS total_records
  FROM user_logs;
  ```

Output:

| total_records |
| --- |
| 44301 |

---

So my intention was to show the "total_records" table when I click a button. So I removed the table and added a code like this:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Output</button>

<p id="output"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "| total_records |
| :-----------: |
|     44301     |";
}
</script>
```

But of course this is not working. I tried experimenting on what to put after the `.innerHTML =` to show the table (e.g. I tried making the table output as an embedded image) but I was unsuccessful.

If I just put a single line plain text after `.innerHTML =`, the button works fine.

Example:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Output</button>

<p id="output"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "This is the output";
}
</script>
```

The above will display "This is the output" after I click the button.

I tried making line breaks to my table like this but it just shows as a plain text (like a table but in messy format) and not a markdown table:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Output</button>

<p id="output"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "| total_records |</br>| :-----------: |</br>|   44301   |";
}
</script>
```

Comment: code looks ok. please share more code or tell exactly what happens when you click output. log some statements to console in the myFunction, see if it's even being called.

Comment: @AbdullahAhmad Thank you for your reply. I edited my question to add some more examples of what I tried. Basically that was the only part of my code that is html which I copied from a tutorial on how to create onclick buttons. The rest is just markdown. It works fine with single line plain texts but I just can't make it work to show a normal markdown table.

Comment: Why are you setting markdown with innerHTML. As the name suggests it expects a string in HTML format, not markdown format

Comment: `</br>` is nonsense. The `br` element **doesn't** have an optional *start tag* and the end tag for it is **forbidden**.

Comment: @mousetail Thank you. I didn't know that as I am very new with this. So, I tried doing it in HTML format but still nothing shows when I click the button.

Answer (score 0):

You have a timing problem.

This is the order that things happen in:

1. The markdown processor converts markdown into HTML
2. The browser renders an HTML document
3. The browser executes JavaScript embedded in the HTML document

(There is some overlap in steps 2 and 3, but that doesn't matter for this example).

You are using JavaScript to assign some markdown to the `innerHTML` property, but since that happens **after** step *1*, the markdown processor isn't going to do anything with it.

If you want to generate content with client-side JavaScript then you need to be assigning HTML, not markdown.

You *could* find a client-side JavaScript markdown processor and use it to convert your markdown to HTML in the browser and then assign its output to `innerHTML`.

---

And that all said, you should write semantic markup. HTML is consumed by and displayed on graphical browsers, text browsers, screen readers, Braille keyboards, search engine indexing bots, and more. Tables are designed to associate rows and columns of data (where everything in each row has something in common and everything in each column has something in common). If you have only two cells, then you don't have tabular data! This looks like you should have a heading and a paragraph under it.

Comment: thank you for your reply. The one row is just an example based on the first sql query I did. But my intention was to do that in all queries later on which will result in more rows/bigger tables. I will research about what you explained. I tried using html code for the table format after `innerHTML=` instead of markdown format but still nothing was happening when I click the button.

Comment: @newbiejellyfish — You've provided three different sets of code. Two of them you said something happened. One of them you said nothing happened but I would have expected it to spit an error message in to the browser console when you loaded the page.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know about browser console. What I was doing is writing down my documentation/codes in a markdown file using VS Code and have a preview of it on the side. I also tried saving it as html file and opened it in the browser. After opening the html file in the browser, two out of the three codes I gave, it is giving an output when I click the button (albeit different than what I was going for). And the other one does nothing. I'll try to play around with it more and see what I can figure out. Thank you very much for your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: "I'm sorry I don't know about browser console" — Now is a good time to learn. https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/web_console/index.html